# Constant TCP_MISS for bundled/minified content in Azure CDN - Standard Akamai

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-cdn, azure-webapps

Our Application setup:

- Azure web app running .NET 4.7 (MVC 5)
- Azure Akamai CDN enabled with "Custom Origin" & "Cache every unique URL" pointing to the MVC app.
- Web App uses Nuget "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization version 1.1.3" for bundling and minification.

Problem: The bundled JS & CSS served from the Azure Akamai CDN always show as a TCP_MISS.

Example URL: https://cdn.somesite.com/Content/Styles/bundlePreview?v=WOktWxTaT0JTWFR4n5uq7yUWk-P2XVrmQNGQWYBW6eg1

[Response Headers of CDN via Postman using a custom header - Pragma: akamai-x-cache-on)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AwNp.jpg)

[Response Headers of the Origin Server for the same above bundled resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc7oB.jpg)

The "Date" & "Expires" header of both the CDN and Origin server gets a new date every time the request is sent via Postman.

Can someone give an idea as to why there is a TCP_MISS only for the bundled JS & CSS? Images & Fonts are cached properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: @AlexShapovalov Nope, we used Gulp to "pre bundle/minify" before deployment and added a query string at the end of the script/style tags. I suggest you do the same, it's not that difficult...